# Docker exec printf gives No such file or directory error

Tags: docker

I am trying to run the following command for an existing docker container:

```
docker exec my_docker printf '%sTest' >> /usr/local/src/test.txt
```

It gives me the following error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/src/test.txt: No such file or directory
```

While when I do the following:

```
docker exec -it my_docker bash
```

And type the same command, everything works just fine. Is there anything that I am missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a good reason for this: it's being interpreted as two commands. Try wrapping the printf command in a command string:

```
docker exec my_docker bash -c 'printf "%sTest" >> /usr/local/src/test.txt'
```

The key is that you've used a bash operator. Similar to any time you run something like:

```
echo one two >> file.txt
```

The ">>" operator doesn't get passed as an argument to echo (like "one" and "two" do). Instead it executes your echo command and appends its output to a file. In this case, the ">>" operator is doing the same to your docker exec, and trying to output the results to `/usr/local/src/scores.txt` and reporting that the directory does not exist (on the host, not the container).

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
docker exec my_docker bash -c "printf '%sTest' >> /usr/local/src/test.txt"
```

To make sure bash is executing the correct command.

Answer (score 0):

The `>>` is getting captured by the shell on your docker host. So it's attempting to output the result of the `docker` command to the filesystem on the host, instead of the output of the `printf` command to the filesystem inside the container. If `/usr/local/src/` doesn't exist on the host, you'll get that error trying to output to a file in that directory.

As others have mentioned, quote the entire string and pass as an argument to `bash -c` to have it processed within the container.